# Segmentation error in Swift array?

Tags: swift

I have array of data, where each element is another array.

I do this :

```
    for array  in data
        {
            let metaD  = array[0]  //should be a string

  // here each "array" object is an array of strings.
```

I could not get rid of this signal segmentation error.

Comment: Can you share more of the surrounding code? Which line causes the error? What is the exact text of the error?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the lack of details, I also did not had more details, anyway,

```
 let thisArray:NSArray = array as! NSArray
            let metaD  = thisArray[0]
```

Solves the problem, so he "knows" its an `NSArray`.

Comment: If `array` is a Swift `Array` then you can just do `let thisArray = array as NSArray`. You should also test to make sure it's non-empty before you use the subscript.

Comment: You should not use `NSArray`in Swift  at all because it doesn't have any type information. Cast `data` to the actual Swift type (probably `[[String]]`) then the compiler does the rest for you.

Comment: @vadian I agree that `NSArray` is not optimal but there are occasions where it is useful. We haven't completely cut the cords of Objective-C yet and we're not likely to anytime soon! In this case I agree, if all you want to do is pull out that `String` then cast to a Swift `Array`.